# Application Loader showing error itms-9000

Tags: certificate

I am not able to upload or deliver my app using application loader. 
Build option not able to upload my app. please help me why this error is coming.

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.myco.myapp [My App.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Apple Developer Portal, recreate the provisioning profile (distribution profile in your case) and download it again. Make sure that the Distribution certificate is installed in your Keychain Access in order to sign apps submitted for the App Store. and check your bundle id as well